# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gitlab

I'm trying to move my GitLab to mysql following [this](https://lessmind.github.io/2016/11/18/gitlab-ce-omnibus-package-with-mysql/). In the process when i try -

```
    $ cd /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
    $ sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle install
```

I get the following error -

> Installing gpgme 2.0.13 with native extensions
>
> Installing nokogiri 1.8.2 with native extensions
>
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory:
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/allocations-1.0.5/ext/liballocations
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180615-5748-1r5uwd8.rb
>   extconf.rb
>
> mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/allocations-1.0.5 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/allocations-1.0.5/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing allocations (1.0.5), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install allocations -v '1.0.5'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

I have tried `sudo gem install allocations -v '1.0.5'` which says one gem successfully built but gives the same error over and over. I have ruby2.5-dev installed also.

**Edit:**

As asked in the comments, this is the config in  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.bundle/config -

---

> BUNDLE_RETRY: "5"
>
> BUNDLE_PATH: "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem"
>
> BUNDLE_JOBS: "9"
>
> BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "true"
>
> BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "development:test:postgres"

If I run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, I get this massive error -

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (gitlab::database_migrations line 49) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20180618-9085-8vou2p" ----
STDOUT: bundler: failed to load command: rake (/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Your bundle is locked to RedCloth (4.3.2), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of RedCloth (4.3.2) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of RedCloth (4.3.2) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
STDERR:
```

Comment: try installing this package `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev` - I think it should include the header files you need (`ruby.h`)

Comment: @meta I have it already installed. Ruby version is 2.5.1. I probably need ruby/2.3.0 as in the error above. But `sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev` gives `Unable to locate package ruby2.3`

Comment: For Ruby I'm not a biggest fan of `apt` package manager, try `rvm` or `rbenv` for maybe better experience?

Comment: I installed ruby2.3 with rvm. Still the error persists.

Comment: Please show us your bundler config `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.bundle/config`

Comment: @Panic edited the question to add the config